# When will this site be merged with the other music proposals?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Particularly, the [guitar stackexchange](https://music.stackexchange.com/).  It was mentioned [here](http://meta.guitars.stackexchange.com/questions/67/shouldnt-we-merge-this-site-with-the-other-music-performance-sites) and [here](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/205/merging-all-music-proposals) (see @Rebecca Chernoff's comment) that they would likely be merged.

Now, I know the music Q&A site literally *just* went out of beta, and I don't want to sound impatient/ungrateful, but I'd really like to know:  **Is there any new word on this?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained in [the link](http://meta.guitars.stackexchange.com/questions/136/announcement-save-guitars-se-by-supporting-the-music-proposal) in [Matthew's answer](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60/when-will-this-site-be-merged-with-the-other-music-proposals/61#61), we'll bring Guitars-SE content in in a week or two, once this community has had some time to get established, and after [pro tem mods](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) have been appointed.

The Area 51 proposals that were related/dupes were closed before this site launched in to private beta.

Comment: Where followers of closed related/dupes "spamed" about this site's public beta?

Comment: Indeed, we don't need to rush the gun yet as adding too much guitar questions at this moment is bad.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: [Guitars was merged a while ago](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170/the-guitars-se-site-has-been-folded-in-to-this-site).

---

[This post on Guitars](http://meta.guitars.stackexchange.com/questions/136/announcement-save-guitars-se-by-supporting-the-music-proposal) should cover all that.  I don't believe there's any new information.  Patience :)