# The Guitars SE site has been folded in to this site

Tags: discussion, content-import

The guitars.stackexchange site did not make it out of public beta.  As such, we have closed that site and folded the content into music.stackexchange.  Rep associated with these posts has been transferred over as well.

These questions have been imported as-is, so they could use some fresh eyes to look over them, make sure they are tagged appropriately, etc.  A list is included below.  Pick some random ones from the list, as many as you want, and take a look at them.

You can also look at questions which are untagged:  https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged

If anyone has any troubles with their accounts matching up with content imported from the old site, please post a new question here on the meta and we will help you out.

For a few days, it will seem like this site is being dominated by guitar questions, but recall that prior to this import, the site was not dominated by guitar questions.  A form of balance will work itself out once these questions get looked at and aren't getting bumped as people clean up the import.

[Visual Sound 1 Spot Power Supply Hum](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/976)
[How do I choose my first guitar for self-learning?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/979)
[How To Improve My Sightreading?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/985)
[What are good beginner books to follow for classical guitar (self study or otherwise) ?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/992)
[What is the technique Adrian Belew utilizes through-out : "Elephant Talk" by King Crimson?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/993)
[What's the difference between the "smooth" strings and the "rough" strings?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/997)
[Why is an amplifier's effects loop useful?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1001)
[using multiple stereo effects](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1004)
[Options for tuning 5-string bass?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1008)
[What Phaser is used at the beginning of "Rooster" by Alice in Chains?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1012)
[What is meant by "Top-End" and "Bottom-End"?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1015)
[Why do some artists tune their guitars half a step or whole step down?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1018)
[What are some chord substitutions for a I-IV-V blues progression?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1024)
[What's a good strategy for adjusting pole pieces?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1026)
[Should I replace unwound strings on my acoustic guitar as often as the wound ones?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1031)
[What are the most popular types or styles of pickups, and what is the genre of music most associated with them?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1033)
[How do you prevent injuries from bad posture while playing classical guitar?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1035)
[The skinny on neck constructions. Is it all about tone?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1038)
[What is the I-vi-ii-V Chord Progressions?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1042)
[Does a covering on a humbucker pickup make a difference?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1046)
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1049
[Balanced triodes. Gimmick, or worth the money?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1051)
[String buzz on bass guitar](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1053)
[What do the different tubes in an amplifier do?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1055)
[Emulating the tone of a Rickenbacker](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1058)
[Is a guitar body made out of mahogany generally lighter than a body made out of alder ?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1061)
[What is a string skipping exercise?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1064)
[Silicon vs Germanium Fuzz](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1069)
[How do I know when it's time to change a tube on my amplifier?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1072)
[Singing notes while playing scales](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1075)
[Guitar produces hum due to poor soldering](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1079)
[Distortion pedals similar to Boss's DS-1](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1082)
[Cheap alternative to a SG Standard](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1085)
[How does scale length affect my playing?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1089)
[Where does picking speed come from? Forearm, hand, or bicep?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1093)
[What are good oils to use on a neck that has been stripped of veneer?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1101)
[What is concert pitch?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1103)
[Putting guitar and song together](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1106)
[Free exercise books](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1111)
[What is the first scale one should learn on guitar](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1115)
[Factors in choosing a replacement saddle for an acoustic guitar.](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1119)
[When should I be concerned about calibrating the bias of vacuum tubes in an amplifier?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1122)
[Effective learning from videos](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1126)
[How can I minimize going out of tune when using the whammy bar?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1130)
[What is a "Circle of Fourths" chord progression?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1136)
[Upgrade tuners or get a new guitar?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1139)
[What are Tone Pots / Potentiometers?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1142)
[Why does my guitar sound more natural when plugged directly into a tube amp vs through a pedal board?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1145)
[What is a good solo to learn in the major scale?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1148)
[Should I worry about painful fingertips?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1151)
[Acoustic guitar - how to wind strings on the tuning posts](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1161)
[What are modes and how are they useful?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1164)
[Is there a way to develop "Perfect Pitch"?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1169)
[Selling my guitar](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1173)
[Where should I put delay pedal, before reverb or after?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1179)
[Vertical wall mount / Holding a guitar by the neck](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1182)
[Can you make your own Leslie Speakers?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1185)
[Kahler tremolo bridge problems - how to test and fix?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1192)
[Tips for playing outdoors in cold weather?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1195)
[Tips on playing with wah-wah for beginners](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1201)
[Is there one or more "proper" finger picking styles/techniques?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1205)
[Where can I find music notes for classical guitar and lute online?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1208)
[Strings stick to pickup poles when the tremolo is depressed.](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1212)
[What is true bypass?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1214)
[Are there any benefits of using a Capo?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1218)
[What Does a Compressor Pedal Do?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1225)
[How to hide a flat pick in the right hand when switching to finger picking, Warren Haynes style](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1227)
[What to look for in an independent luthier?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1232)
[What is the difference between upstrokes and downstrokes while strumming a guitar?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1235)
[Mark Knopfler picking finger patterns — Sultans of Swing intro](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1240)
[What to do? Programming, bass playing and RSI](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1243)
["one finger per fret" - is it worth following this rule?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1247)
[Where/When did the modern guitar originate?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1256)
[What is a good guitar solo to learn in the minor scale?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1258)
[What is a good solo to learn in the Dorian mode?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1262)
[Mental approach to improvisation](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1266)
[How to play upstrokes with our hand when playing an acoustic guitar?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1268)
[Why is an adjustable bridge needed?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1271)
[Acoustic Guitar Intonation Adjustments](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1273)
[Deep clean sound from Pod X3](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1277)
[Is it necessary to learn the names of fret notes?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1279)
[What are the advantages of learning to play on your own versus learning from a teacher?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1285)
[We got together with another guitarist. What can we play together?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1295)
[Do acoustic or classical guitars need to be set up?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1301)
[Epiphone SG-400 and straps](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1305)
[Does leaving a capo on "hurt" the strings?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1308)
[How do you mic a guitar amp?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1311)
[Why do tube-based guitar amplifiers sound so good?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1317)
[Multi-Effects Pedal or Multiple Effects Pedals?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1322)
[Do veneered tops on electric guitars really matter?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1330)
[Fretted notes sound 'off' when another string is bent](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1332)
[Recommended arm and hand position for neck side](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1335)
[Guitar practice: more often but less time or once in a few days but for a few hours?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1338)
[What changes in the amp when I adjust its presence?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1345)
[Why does my guitar go out of tune after I play it a while?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1348)
[In phase, out of phase pickups](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1354)
[Is anyone able to outline the purpose of these controls?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1359)
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1361
[Why is dropped D tuning used so often?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1363)
[What's causing this buzzing sound on the high e string?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1368)
[How do you care for your guitar?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1372)
[Symbols "M", "C", "D", and "P" in Guitar Tablature](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1379)
[How do I set up a bass guitar?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1383)
[is there any free tab viewer for GuitarPro files?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1386)
[How should I tune a guitar with a Floyd Rose tremolo?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1391)
[How to do "metal" harmonics (pinch etc)](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1394)
[Can I wind my own pickups?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1401)
[What are the benefits and drawbacks of active pickups?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1410)
[Special concerns for short-scale basses?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1413)
[Playing clean arpeggios on a lapsteel guitar](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1415)
[Best method to learn to play barre chords?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1419)
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1428
[What are good resources for learning music theory?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1439)
[Should I look at the fretboard while I play guitar?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1446)
[How do Pre War Martin Guitars Differ From Modern Ones?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1453)
[How to begin learning the CAGED Method](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1455)
[What is the difference between analog and digital effects pedals?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1458)
[What is a guitar truss rod?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1462)
[Do I need to have my guitar re-set up if I change the string gauge](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1467)
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1472
[What is the the Nashville Numbers system?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1480)
[How do you tune your guitar?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1482)
[How to accurately intonate a 3 saddle telecaster?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1490)
[What effect(s) were used in the intro to Cowboys from hell by Pantera?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1494)
[How do you identify a good acoustic guitar?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1496)
[Does this guitar tuning have a name?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1505)
[Arthritis In Hands (Playing With Pain In Hands) - Are There Recommended Approaches?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1507)
[Changing the strings: one by one, or by taking all strings off at one time?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1511)
[How to Calibrate / Setup an Electric Guitar?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1519)
[How can I effectively secure guitar strings to the tuning pegs?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1523)
[Why is the bridge pickup on a Stratocaster angled?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1526)
[How can I 'clean' up my bass fretting?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1530)
[Why does my thumb hurt when I play bar chords?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1533)
[How often should I replace the strings on my guitar?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1538)
[Cleaning the fretboard of an electric guitar](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1553)
[What electric guitar string set should I use to go down to B?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1561)
[Why is my guitar's saddle at an angle?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1567)
[What are the benefits and drawbacks of the Floyd Rose SpeedLoader tremolo system?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1570)
[Pick weight - functional difference, or just personal preference?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1573)
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1580
[Properly fingering jazz chords?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1582)
[Ten Minute Practice Techniques For Guitar?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1585)
["х" on tablature - how do I play it?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1594)
[Varying rhythms on bass](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1596)
[Beginning Slap Bass](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1602)
[What is intonation and how can I find out if my guitar has correct intonation?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1604)
[How do I set up an electric guitar?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1612)
[Fingers and fretboard](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1615)
[What is a piezo pickup and how does it differ to a common pickup?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1619)
[What is the best way of learning the notes on the fretboard.](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1621)
[Coated Strings—Gimmick, or worth the money?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1629)
[Quality Bass Effects Brands](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1637)
[I am bored with a metronome, should I get a drum machine?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1642)
[Hot guitar pickup](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1647)
[How do you determine if you're ready to join a band?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1652)
[What kind of guitar exercise is "the caterpillar"?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1657)
[how to do the Dimebag Squeal?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1659)
[What time signatures are used in flamenco and related styles?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1661)
[Using alternative tunings](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1663)
[How do I improve my picking and fretting speed?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1672)
[Do guitar strings wear when not used?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1677)
[What should I look for in a good metronome?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1683)
[Amp picking up radio stations](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1687)
[Poor quality guitars that don't tune](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1691)
[How can I practice in an apartment without annoying the neighbours?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1695)
[How should I mic up an acoustic guitar?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1709)
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1712
[Damaged tremolo arm hole in Edge 3 bridge...](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1714)
[How to achieve a glassy, edgy solo tone?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1718)
[Why is the guitar tuned like it is?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1723)
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1727
[How do I find a good reverb pedal for a huge, soul-filling sound?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1734)
[Steve Gaines and Ed King... Love their playing, have a hard time emulating it...](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1739)
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1742
[Bach's Bourree BWV 996 timing issue](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1746)
[My guitar goes out of tune at a higher pitch rather than lower, is that normal?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1749)
[How do I write good tablature?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1754)
[What are some harmonic options for layering guitar lines while recording?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1758)
[What can be done about a buzzy sitar-like fret?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1763)
[Tips playing F barre chord](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1767)
[How can I stop my electric guitar strings from rusting so quickly?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1773)
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1778
[Wireless Guitar Systems](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1784)
[Is it possible to mute some of my strings?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1787)
[How to play chords like G/B](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1793)
[What is the "theory" behind "odd time signatures"?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1796)
[How do I go about de-fretting a bass guitar?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1801)
[Is it possible to strum (with a pick) separated strings?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1805)
[Any advice for a novice composer?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1809)
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1818
[How do I properly stretch my newly strung strings?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1821)
[Up-down strumming when playing fingerstyle](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1827)
[Should a Floyd Rose bridge be parallel to the body of the guitar?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1834)
[Glossary of Guitar Effects](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1838)
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1847
[What is the Linear Harmonic Transform?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1857)
[Why does my Stratocaster guitar sound worse with new strings?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1859)
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1863
[Advance Plucking Lessons](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1867)
[Why is the guitar traditionally held by a strap, and not in the lap?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1869)
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1875
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1881
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1883
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1887
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1893
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1897
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1900
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1904
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1908
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1913
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1917
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1932
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1936
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1941
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1944
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1948
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1951
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1956
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1958
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1960
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1965
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1969
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1971
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1977
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1983
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1985
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1992
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1995
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1999
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2002
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2005
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2009
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2015
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2019
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2022
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2028
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2032
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2036
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2040
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2043
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2047
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2050
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2052
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2055
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2058
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2060
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2070
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2072
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2075
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2080
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2084
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2089
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2096
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2099
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2103
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2108
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2113
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2115
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2119
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2124
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2126
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2129
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2137
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2141
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2144
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2149
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2152
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2157
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2162
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2164
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2166
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2169
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2175
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2179
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2188
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2190
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2196
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2202
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2207
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2212
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2214
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2217
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2220
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2224
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2230
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2234
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2238
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2244
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2248
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2250
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2254
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2257
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2262
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2265
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2270
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2280
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2282
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2284
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2288
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2290
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2295
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2298
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2304
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2308
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2312
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2316
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2320
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2326
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2330
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2337
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2340
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2345
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2348
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2354
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2359
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2361
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2364
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2368
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2372
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2375
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2380
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2382
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2386
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2390
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2393
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2396
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2398
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2403
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2406
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2414
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2418
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2421
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2424
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2427
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2435
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2440
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2445
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2449
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2454
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2457
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2461
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2466
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2472
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2475
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2477
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2479
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2483
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2486
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2491
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2495
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2499
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2501
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2505
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2511
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2513
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2518
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2525
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2527
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2530
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2536
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2544
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2547
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2552
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2554
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2556
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2562
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2565
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2568
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2571
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2574
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2577
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2580
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2582
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2587
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2592
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2595
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2598
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2602
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2609
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2611
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2616
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2624
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2627
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2630
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2636
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2638
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2644
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2648
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2650
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2654
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2658
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2662
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2667
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2670
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2673
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2676
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2680
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2685
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2687
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2690
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2696
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2699
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2702
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2708
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2710
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2712
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2717
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2720
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2726
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2728
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2730
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2732
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2737
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2741
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2745
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2749
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2754
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2757
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2771
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2778
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2781
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2784
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2787
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2792
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2795
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2799
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2801
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2807
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2811
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2814
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2819
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2822
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2824
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2829
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2834
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2837
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2843
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2846
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2849
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2852
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2858
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2861
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2866
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2868
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2871
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2873
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2875
https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2878

Comment: now I see.. I was wondering why so many guitars questions popping up this morning

Comment: I think that not all badges have been carried over. There will probably a rep recalc some time in the near future?

Comment: I noticed that the Jtab plugin hasn't come over in the merger, will there be a more general musical replacement, will we need to re-add the tabs in answers?

Comment: @ogerard I think a site-wide recalc was already done, I had my rep from Guitars added immediately after the import. I also did a recalc for myself manually (you can do it [here](http://music.stackexchange.com/reputation)) and there was no change.

Comment: @Matthew : I thought that because I saw several top former Guitar users with several bronze badges but no silver badges, and I presumed it was a calculation/migration artefact.

Comment: @ogerard Oh, I somehow totally missed your mention of badges. I would assume there is no plan to import badges, but badges related to the info still attached to the questions (e.g. "Nice Answer" for 10+ upvotes) should have been caught by the automagic script. I'd suggest flagging the post in question if you notice the user doesn't have the appropriate badge for it.

Comment: @Matthew, @Rebecca : After looking more closely, there are badges missing corresponding to enlightened, and Beta: you cannot have the enlightened badge if accepted flag were not imported. Also the Beta badge/Precog badge are specific to the private beta of this site so were not recalculated for private beta members of Guitar. This will also be a problem for Yearling. For instance jduv is seen as member for 37 days but he signed up for Guitar before that.

Comment: @ogerard I would say that site-specific badges like that should not be carried over, even if the old site is basically a subset of this one. We want to encourage them to do the same good work for this site as they did for the old one. Their previous work is recognized by rep and the non-site-specific badges.

Answer (score 5):

Additionally, it looks like accepted answers were not carried over.  Those of you who come here from Guitars, or already were here, please evaluate whether you wish to re-accept the answer you did before or wait for new answers, and proceed accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

I've retagged a bunch of them. And I'm positive that folks will probably decide that different tags would have been better choices, so go for it.

And don't be shy, you'll get an [Organizer badge](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/badges/5/organizer) for your first retag.