# Guitar questions everywhere!?

Tags: discussion, guitars

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The Guitars SE site has been folded in to this site](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170/the-guitars-se-site-has-been-folded-in-to-this-site)

This site seems to have totally gone to pot. All I see when I log on these days is a long stream of questions about guitars or guitar music! They absolutely flood out all other questions about non-guitar (i.e. the vast majority) of music.

Why has this sudden transformation occurred? Is anyone else similarly disappointed by this flood of very localised questions on a general music site?

Comment: Try [the "Newest" view](http://music.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest) instead of the "Active" view. The imported Guitars questions are being edited, and thus are "Active".

Comment: Feel like I should say something, as I am contributing to this incident, I have been retagging a massive amount of merged questions, hence they all come up under the 'active' column of the homepage. Once everything is organized, things will return to normal.

Comment: @Matthew: Oh, I had no idea about this! There should really be a message on the main part of the site so visitors (even existing members like me) aren't scared off. Cheers for the tip though.

Comment: @Alistair: Ok, that's useful to know. Retagging them is a good thing in the long-run; I just wish there was were provisions so that they didn't all just swamp the front page....

Comment: @Noldrin: up voted back to zero for you. Also: tags are going to become everyone's friend as we keep stuff we don't want to see out of the question view. :)

Comment: @Noldorin It is on the main site, text banner just below the header. And chill with the name-calling please.

Comment: @Matthew: What name-calling? Do you know what name-calling actually is? I had the right to say that thanks; don't appreciate the butting in.

Comment: @Ian C: Thanks. I just get annoyed when no comment is left sometimes, but appreciate it now! I guess we just have to wait for this import to die down...

Comment: ALSO: there is no banner for me about this merge. I see absolutely nothing on the main site.