# Can anyone tell me what happened to Guitar Theory forum site?

Tags: support, guitars, questions

I remember months before I subscribed to another forum site from stackExchange for Guitar by name guitar theory (or may be a different name, but something with Guitar.) I couldnt find that website any more. I had an account and asked a question about chords and was answered. Now I want to get back to that answer as it really had some great tips for me to practice. Can anyone help me to retrieve that particular question of mine.

I didnt know where to post this question. If this is posted in a wrong place can some one redirect me to the right place to post this question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [The Guitars SE site has been folded in to this site](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170/the-guitars-se-site-has-been-folded-in-to-this-site)

If your question was migrated here, just search and you'll find it.  If not I believe it's gone for good.

Comment: o.. ok.. Thanks for that.. I found my question http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2080/what-is-the-practical-theory-behind-applying-chords-for-a-song. Now how can I transfer all my questions and answers and rep from that site to this. I just recently created an account here..

Comment: @franklins If you go down to the bottom of the page there's a "contact us" link, shoot them an email explaining and linking to the questions you'd like to be associated with your account.

Comment: Thank you.. I will do that right now..